# How does Pathfinder "Insanity" defense work with Great Old Ones?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat

In Pathfinder Bestiary 4 ([so says the website](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary4/greatOldOne.html)) The Great Old Ones have a defensive ability listed as "Insanity" with a save DC. How does that work? (How do I apply that to a game?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [Great Old One subtype](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#subtype-great-old-one):

> Insanity (Ex) Any creature that attempts to interact directly with a Great Old One's thoughts (such as via detect thoughts or telepathy) must succeed at a Will save or be driven permanently insane. The save DC is equal to 10 + 1/2 the Great Old One's Hit Dice + the Great Old One's Charisma modifier. This duplicates the effect of the insanity spell, or the insanity rules (in which case the save DC is also the ongoing insanity DC). A Great Old One using its telepathy to communicate doesn't activate this ability unless it spends a standard action to focus its mind on one opponent. This is a mind-affecting effect.